# Prove that piecewise defined multivariable function is differentiable at the origin

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x,y)$
=\begin{cases} 
                 x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})+y^2, & x\neq0 \\
     \
                 y^2, & x=0
                \end{cases}

I've been trying to prove it's differentiable at $(0,0)$ using the definition.   Now
$\frac{\partial{f(0,0)}}{\partial{x}}=0=\frac{\partial{f(0,0)}}{\partial{y}}$, $L$(h,k)$\equiv$$0$ and 
$$
 \frac{|f(0 + h, 0 + k) - f(0, 0)|}{\sqrt{h^{2} + k^{2}}} =\frac{|f(h,k) - f(0, 0)|}{\sqrt{h^{2} + k^{2}}}=\frac{|h^2\sin(1/h)+k^2 - 0^2|}{\sqrt{h^{2} + k^{2}}}=\frac{|h^2\sin(1/h)+k^2 |}{\sqrt{h^{2} + k^{2}}}  
$$...aand I am stuck. I have tried to canlcel out the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

As $(h,k) \to (0,0)$, one may conclude with
$$
\frac{|h^2\sin(1/h)+k^2 |}{\sqrt{h^{2} + k^{2}}} \le \frac{|h^2\sin(1/h)|+|k^2 |}{\sqrt{h^{2} + k^{2}}} \le \frac{h^2+k^2 }{\sqrt{h^{2} + k^{2}}} =\sqrt{h^{2} + k^{2}} \to 0,
$$ since $|\sin x|\le1$ for any real number $x$.

Comment: @1_likeMaths Are you Ok with my answer above? Or are you wanting me to make some improvements?